# Array - object or simple variable?

Tags: java, arrays, object

In java, arrays can be created as int[] arr = {value1, value2, value3,.....}. Here we are not using the "new" keyword.So how do we say that array is an object in java?

Comment: It's using literal notation. Just as you can do `String a = "b";` and don't have to do `String a = new String("b");` and `a` is still an object, the array is declared and initialized with a literal without `new` and is still an object.

Comment: It depends, as with most implementations of most languages, all memory allocated by you is allocated as an object. Though some people subscribe to the idea that only `class` objects are _really_ objects, which I hate, but I suppose it does clear up ambiguity when talking about a language like Java in everyday terms.

Comment: It's just a syntax shortcut, array can still be created with `new` keyword like `int[] ints = new int[10];`

Comment: -Andrew Li String a = "b" is related to "b" present in the string pool .Can you please explain in context to array?

Answer (score 0):

The Java language specification says so (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html):

> In the Java programming language, arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are
>   dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object
>   (§4.3.2). All methods of class Object may be invoked on an array.

Answer (score 0):

Java specifications says: "An object is a class instance or an array. "